# Is there a way to restrict time zone options in the DateTimeRange field widget?

Tags: 8, datetime

Is there a way to limit the options of the timezone field in the datetime or datetime range widget in Drupal 8? It currently shows tons of timezones, but we really only need about 10 options. I checked the default widget but did not see anything about how it was building that part of the widget form.

The core DateTime element appears to do:

```
$element['timezone'] = [
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => system_time_zones(FALSE, TRUE),
        // Default to user's time zone.
        '#default_value' => $element['#date_timezone'],
        '#required' => $element['#required'],
      ];
```

I guess the only way is to alter this element and configure the timezones that should be selectable?

Comment: I just added a datetime range widget and it doesn't have timezone settings - maybe you have something like [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/datetime_range_timezone) installed?

Comment: It's possible - I'll check it out. It's a new project. Thanks!

Comment: Not in the project - perhaps it is something else. Still looking.

Comment: Try searching for uses of `system_time_zones`, that's probably the most likely function to have been used for the options

Comment: The core DateTime element does that for options.

Comment: I would just use form_alter and remove the options that are not in your preset list.

Comment: Form alter works on a simple date field added to an entity such as on the user profile page; but no luck so far altering this list when it is on a date field in a paragraph.